# Need help using grep to extract names from list

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line, grep

I have this list of players and I want to get players full name followed by 9 or less characters, I am using the [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) command in Linux.

I tried the following, but it didn't work the way I expected :
`cat players.txt | grep -E ' .[0-9]_\('`

Here is a sample of the data I am working with (part of the players.txt file)

```
* Ron_Springett_(1959-1966),_33_Caps
* Alex_Stepney_(1968),_1_Cap
* Nobby_Stiles_(1965-1970),_28_Caps
* Mike_Summerbee_(1968-1973),_8_Caps
* Peter_Swan_(1960-1962),_19_Caps
* Bobby_Tambling_(1962-1966),_3_Caps
* Derek_Temple_(1965),_1_Cap
* Peter_Thompson_(1964-1970),_16_Caps
* Robert_Thomson_(1963-1964),_8_Caps
* Terry_Venables_(1964),_2_Caps
* Dennis_Viollet_(1960-1961),_2_Caps
* Anthony_Waiters_(1964),_5_Caps
* Gordon_West_(1968-1969),_3_Caps
* Frank_Wignall_(1964),_2_Caps
* Ray_Wilson_(1960-1968),_63_Caps
* Tommy_Wright_(1968-1970),_11_Caps
* Gerald_Young_(1964),_1_Cap
```

Comment: cat players.txt | grep -E ' .[0-9]_\('
the list is to big so i just put an example

Comment: this command will display the text and the grep space match any characters 9 or less

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's being asked here. Please include some expected output.

Comment: Check this out.  I think you are headed down the wrong path with grep.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300453/parts-of-a-match-in-regular-expression-with-egrep

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat vague, but this looks more or less like what you're trying to do.

```
cat players.txt | perl -ne '
    s/_/ /g; 
    /([A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+).*?([0-9-]+)/ && print "$1 \t $2\n"
'

Ron Springett    1959-1966
Alex Stepney     1968
Nobby Stiles     1965-1970
Mike Summerbee   1968-1973
Peter Swan   1960-1962
Bobby Tambling   1962-1966
Derek Temple     1965
Peter Thompson   1964-1970
Robert Thomson   1963-1964
Terry Venables   1964
Dennis Viollet   1960-1961
Anthony Waiters      1964
Gordon West      1968-1969
Frank Wignall    1964
Ray Wilson   1960-1968
Tommy Wright     1968-1970
Gerald Young     1964
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Fowled by 9 characters or less", but assuming you want a full name of no longer than 9 characters, it's `' .{0,9}_('`.

Comment: I am sure he means "followed by 9 characters or less". So the full name + 9 or less characters.

Comment: yes, thanks it did work but you for got \    ' .{0,9}_\('  thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but if you want the extract player names and year/year-range, you can do it like this with grep:

```
<players.txt grep -Eo '[^ *][^)]+\)' | tr '_' ' '
```

tr translates the underscores to space, output:

```
Ron Springett (1959-1966)
Alex Stepney (1968)
Nobby Stiles (1965-1970)
Mike Summerbee (1968-1973)
Peter Swan (1960-1962)
Bobby Tambling (1962-1966)
Derek Temple (1965)
Peter Thompson (1964-1970)
Robert Thomson (1963-1964)
Terry Venables (1964)
Dennis Viollet (1960-1961)
Anthony Waiters (1964)
Gordon West (1968-1969)
Frank Wignall (1964)
Ray Wilson (1960-1968)
Tommy Wright (1968-1970)
Gerald Young (1964)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as per your question;

```
grep -Eo '[A-Za-z_]+\([0-9-]{0,9}\)' players.txt

Ron_Springett_(1959-1966)
Alex_Stepney_(1968)
Nobby_Stiles_(1965-1970)
Mike_Summerbee_(1968-1973)
Peter_Swan_(1960-1962)
Bobby_Tambling_(1962-1966)
Derek_Temple_(1965)
Peter_Thompson_(1964-1970)
Robert_Thomson_(1963-1964)
Terry_Venables_(1964)
Dennis_Viollet_(1960-1961)
Anthony_Waiters_(1964)
Gordon_West_(1968-1969)
Frank_Wignall_(1964)
Ray_Wilson_(1960-1968)
Tommy_Wright_(1968-1970)
Gerald_Young_(1964)
```

If you need additional formatting, I would suggest to use sed instead of grep.